# Tensorflow reports 'TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected' when using tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow to code a model. Part of my conditional statement like:

```
new_shape = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(src_shape)[0], 2), lambda: src_shape, lambda: tf.constant([1, src_shape[0]]))
```

and `src_shape` is the result of `tf.shape()`.

It reports `TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected`. I know it is because `tf.constant([1, src_shape[0]])` is a list of tensors, but I don't know how to implement my code in a legal way.

I have try to remove `tf.constant()` like

```
new_shape = tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(src_shape)[0], 2), lambda: src_shape, lambda: [1, src_shape[0]])
```

but it reports `ValueError: Incompatible return values of true_fn and false_fn: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use tf.stack, which stacks a list of rank-R tensors into one rank-(R+1) tensor.

```
lambda: tf.stack([1, src_shape[0]], axis=0)
```

Another solution would be using tf.concat using the right tf.reshape commands.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that `tf.convert_to_tensor([1, src_shape[0]])` works. It is an alternative solution.